# Failed to fetch errors when trying to install anything

Tags: apt, package-management

I first tried to download in terminal

```
$ java
Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless  # version 11.0.13+8-0ubuntu1~21.10, or

sudo apt install default-jre              # version 2:1.11-72

sudo apt install openjdk-17-jre-headless  # version 17.0.1+12-1~21.10

sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless   # version 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~21.10

sudo apt install openjdk-15-jre-headless  # version 15.0.3+3-1

sudo apt install openjdk-16-jre-headless  # version 16.0.1+9-1`
```

Then I typed

```
sudo apt install default-jre
```

it said

```
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.ni.net.tr/ubuntu/pool/main/j/java-common/java-common_0.72build1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 95.173.191.11 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.ni.net.tr/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-lts/openjdk-11-jre-headless_11.0.13%2b8-0ubuntu1%7e21.10_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 95.173.191.11 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.ni.net.tr/ubuntu/pool/main/j/java-common/default-jre-headless_1.11-72build1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 95.173.191.11 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.ni.net.tr/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-lts/openjdk-11-jre_11.0.13%2b8-0ubuntu1%7e21.10_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 95.173.191.11 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.ni.net.tr/ubuntu/pool/main/j/java-common/default-jre_1.11-72build1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 95.173.191.11 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.ni.net.tr/ubuntu/pool/main/j/java-atk-wrapper/libatk-wrapper-java_0.38.0-2ubuntu3_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 95.173.191.11 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.ni.net.tr/ubuntu/pool/main/j/java-atk-wrapper/libatk-wrapper-java-jni_0.38.0-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 95.173.191.11 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Then I tried

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headles
```

but it said

```
E: Unable to locate package openjdk-11-jre-headles
```

I just switched from Windows and I am struggling to install java on my newly installed Ubuntu. If you can help me i will be very happy thank you.

I've found that I cant download anything at the moment as it always says unable to fetch. I think I messed up something before.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which version?

Comment: Did you run "sudo apt-get update" as bash in the terminal suggested?

Comment: Try also another mirror.

Comment: @Pilot6 yes iam using ubuntu and version 21.10

Comment: @GuillaumeF93 yes i tried it but didnt worked same problem

Comment: @pLumo i tried other ones but same problem some of them said unable to fetch or unable to locate package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello somehow i solved the problem bu changing my download server i remembered that i changed my default server to http://mirror.ni.net.tr which was not working than i scanned for the best server for me it was ubuntu.torhost.com which worked fine that i could download what i want in terminal.
Note: thanks for who answered my question to help me :)